# Update a table and display updated rows with a single SQL command

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, sql-returning

I need your help with PostgreSQL. I have a homework in which I have to update a column of a table and display all the information that has been updated, but I have to use a single command to do all that. Even worse, I just can use basic clauses like SELECT, UPDATE, SET, WHERE etc.

Is this possible? I didn't find any example.

I've tried several combinations like:

```
SELECT * FROM customer 
(UPDATE custumer SET bithdate = bithdate + INTERVAL '1 DAY'
 WHERE   bithcity = 'New York');
```

This didn't work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is homework, I'll leave something for you.

#### Single SQL statement

Start reading about the [**`RETURNING`** clause of the `UPDATE` command in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html).

Another alternative (for more complex scenarios) would be a [data-modifying CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING). You still need the `RETURNING` clause for that.

Or you could [create a function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html) you can call in a single statement, but that would violate your requirement of only using simple DML commands.

#### Single transaction

If more than a single statement is allowed, another option would be a simple `UPDATE` plus simple `SELECT` wrapped into a [transaction](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tutorial-transactions.html).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your tip! That works very good.  Do you know if there is another way to do the same without using RETURNING. I mean, just using SELECT, UPDATE SET and other basics clauses. My teacher has said we must use only clauses we've learned until now and RETURNING is not included.